# Is there a way to check if a variable is a time in hour : minute time zone format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need help with cleaning a single column of my dataframe that contains either date or time depending on the row. I want to pull the date out and list it in a separate column for every timestamp row.  How do I use iterrows, datetime, and a conditional statement to do this?

I'm doing a web scraping personal project to pull tidal charts into a pandas dataframe. I managed to scrape the data successfully, but the resultant dataframe is a bit disorganized and I'm trying to clean it up.  My problem is that the first column of the dataframe lists the current date and the subsequent rows list a series of times for that date that correspond to high tide, low tide, etc. I want to pull the date out of that column and create a new one where it is listed for every time stamp and I want to use a conditional to check if the row is in a date format or in a time format. 
I know I can use iterrows to go through the rows one by one, and I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use datetime.time.hour and datetime.time.minute in some way, but I'm unclear on how.

A simple version of this problem would be if you had a single column of the dataframe parsed into an array that alternated time and date values:

```
array1 = ['1 January', '12:00 AM', '2 January, '1:00AM', etc.]
```

how would you remove the dates and put them in a separate column? (or array in this case.) I should add that you would have another array that contains time values for the corresponding entries in array1 that have dates and no values for the time entries:

```
array2 = ['12 PM', NaN, '1 PM', Nan, etc.]
```

for clarification I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse and scrape the HTML so I'm pretty sure all the values are strings. Also the actual dataframe doesn't necessarily have the same space between date values, **i.e they don't alternate so I can't just remove every other value**.

Comment: Can you share scraping source URL ?

Comment: https://www.tide-forecast.com/locations/Pearlington-Pearl-River-Mississippi/tides/latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend to use `dateparser` to convert `str` to proper `datetime` format:

```py
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('1 January')
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse('12:00 AM')
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 30, 0, 0)
```

> how would you remove the dates and put them in a separate column?

I would use standard list loop:

```py
dates = []
times = []
for v in array1:
    if any(w in v for w in ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April']):  # to be continued
        dates.append(v)
    elif any(w in v for w in ['AM', 'PM']):
        times.append(v)
    else:
        raise Exception("Undetected")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Time' module.

```
import time

#Basic time and date can be extracted using:  
date_time = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
```

After, you can split it by deleting the spaces and select the listed items you want to keep to another variable.

```
splitted = date_time.split(' ')    
time = splitted[<integer here>] #<< Since this is a list, you can select the items you want to assign to the variable.
```

After that you can compare it in a statement.
Make sure to print the variable you have splited so you know you have selected the right items from the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly you want to make another column with an existing column in dataframe like:

```
d = {'col1': ['1 January', '12:00 AM', '2 February', '1:00AM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# can use regex like
df['col2'] = df[ df['col1'].str.contains ("^\d:|^\d\d:", regex = True)]
```

OR

```
# if want the months like
df['col2'] = df[ df['col1'].str.contains ('Jan|Feb')]
df
```